# Can a muslim man marry a spiritual monotheist woman?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, interfaith

Can a muslim man marry a woman who believes in one god but is spiritual and does not believe in religion?

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

The majority opinion is that Muslims are not allowed to marry non-muslims, monotheists or otherwise, unless they **follow a known and attested divine revelation**. This is based on the literal interpretation of the following verse:

> [Quran 5:5](https://quran.com/5/5) ... And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among
>   the believers and chaste women from among **those who were given the
>   Scripture before you** ...

Classical scholars have used the above to establish prohibition of marrying Zoroastrians, Sabeans and Hanifs etc. even though they are monotheists, the same would extend to a *Spiritual Monotheist*.

[Imam Nawawi in Minhaj Al Talibin:](https://archive.org/stream/MinhajTalibinNawawi#page/n383/mode/2up)  (english [trans](https://archive.org/stream/minhaj_al-talibin_english#page/n311/mode/2up))

> يحرم نكاح من لا كتاب لها كوثنية ومجوسية وتحل كتابية لكن تكره حربية
>   وكذا ذمية على الصحيح والكتابية يهودية أو نصرانية لا متمسكة بالزبور
>   وغيره
>
> Forbidden for marriage those without a Book, such as the idolators and
>   magians. It is permissible to marry people of the Book, but it is
>   makruh (disliked) when they are from a nation with which the Muslims
>   are at war, and it is correct when they are Dhimmis (subjects of a
>   Muslim state). The People of the Book are Jews and Christians, but not
>   those only based on the Zabur (Psalms) etc.

[Tafsir Qurtubi on 5:5](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=5&tSoraNo=5&tAyahNo=5&tDisplay=yes&Page=2&Size=1&LanguageId=1)

> وأما المجوس فالعلماء مجمعون ـ إلا من شَذّ منهم ـ على أن ذبائحهم لا
>   تؤكل ولا يتزوّج منهم؛ لأنهم ليسوا أهل كتاب على المشهور عند العلماء.
>
> Regarding Magians, its the consensus of the ulema, except for a group
>   which dissented, that their slaughtered will not be eaten nor will
>   they be married, because the majority view of the scholars is that they
>   are not people of the book.

[Tafsir Qurtubi on 2:221](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=5&tSoraNo=2&tAyahNo=221&tDisplay=yes&Page=4&Size=1&LanguageId=1)

> وٱختلفوا في نكاح نساءِ المجوس؛ فمنع مالكٌ والشافعيّ وأبو حنيفة
>   والأُوزاعيُّ وإسحاقُ من ذلك. وقال ٱبن حَنْبل: لا يعجبني.
>
> Regarding marrying Magian women, there is a difference of opinion.
>   Imam Malik,  Imam Shafi, Imam Abu Hanifa, Awzari and Ishaq have
>   proclaimed its prohibition. Imam Ahmed bin Hanbal said: I don't like
>   it.